# Is this intl.dateTimeFormat bug?

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I try to use intl.dateTimeFormat on this site: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

it works OK with provided examples but if I write `'hr-HR'` instead of `'en-US'` and if I press "Run", it displays this:

```
"20. 12. 2012."
```

which is incorrect.

The correct value is `"20.12.2012"` (no spaces after dots, no dot after year).
Is someone else saw that? Is that a bug?

Comment: Seems like [that is the correct format for Croatia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Croatia)

Answer (score 0):

Try `de-EN` locale

```js
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-EN').format(date));
```

Comment: Yes it works like that, but still, when using 'hr-HR' it display wrong values and it looks like bug for me.